# AOP logging in Spring services

Tags: spring, aop, transactional

I have a Spring service like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void updateMyObject(MyObject transientObject)
            throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

The transaction management config is like this:

```
    <tx:advice id="transactionInterceptor" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor pointcut=" execution(* service.*Service.*(..))"
            advice-ref="transactionInterceptor" />
    </aop:config>
```

How can I do logging transactionally using an Aspect when the method updateMyObject run? could you please provide me a simple example.

Comment: What do you mean by "logging transactionally"? You typically log to the console or to a file, and those are not transactional resources. Anyway, the idea of StackOverflow is that you try something, and ask a question, showing what you tried, if you have a problem. Not to ask for examples without trying anything.

Comment: I log to database and I have a Spring logService also. whe I try something like this it doesn't work: @Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
 
 @Before("execution(* com.mkyong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(..))")
 public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
 
  System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
  System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
  System.out.println("******");
 }
 
}

Comment: Post that i your question, not in a comment. And tell **how** it doesn't work.